# Apache: mod-rewrite to look up missing images in another directory

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am new to Apache mod rewrite. What I would like to achieve is this.

If an image (gif, jpg, png) is requested from an url and is not found there, it should automatically try to deliver this image from another directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# if there's no file at the requested path..
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# then, if it's an image file, try the other path:
RewriteRule /([^/]*\.(gif|png|jpg))$ /images/path/$1
```

This will act on every image file request that these rules are applied to; to restrict to just a specific "original" directory, then adjust as needed:

```
RewriteRule ^/old/images/path/([^/]*\.(gif|png|jpg))$ /images/path/$1
```

And if you're putting this in `.htaccess` or changing the `RewriteBase`, change accordingly.

Comment: thanks, yes i am putting this in a .htaccess file which is in the root of the website's directory on the server. now should the rewritebase be / or /pathto/websitebase/

Comment: @clamp That `.htaccess` will give you a `RewriteBase` of `/`, which will work just fine.  You'll just want to change the rules that you insert to work correctly in that context; so, for instance with the second rule example I gave, you'd change it to just strip the leading slashes: `RewriteRule ^old/images/path/([^/]*\.(gif|png|jpg))$ images/path/$1`