# Apache2 retrieve files from another folder when not found

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

While working on an application rewrite, I'd like to keep the old app webroot files as a fallback, when the new files are not found.

There are 2 applications:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName legacy.dev
    DocumentRoot /www/legacy/webroot
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName new.dev
    DocumentRoot /www/new/webroot
</VirtualHost>
```

How could I setup the new.dev VirtualHost to retrieve the files present in the DocumentRoot, but if the file is not found, retrieve the files in the legacy.dev DocumentRoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like [What is Apache's equivalent of Nginx's try_files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/290784/what-is-apaches-equivalent-of-nginxs-try-files) would do what you want.

`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://app_cluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]`

tries to look for the file and if it doesn't find it passes it to the apache proxy.  [Apache: mod-rewrite to look up missing images in another directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/311820/apache-mod-rewrite-to-look-up-missing-images-in-another-directory) shows a similar example of using mod_rewrite to do something similar without the proxying.  As you can see it uses a similar `RewriteCond` but a rather different `RewriteRule` which may be easier to work with.

As you may note the first referenced answer is trying to hack nginx's `try-files` into apache so maybe you'd be happier with nginx directly in this case.  [How does try_files work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/329592/how-does-try-files-work) should give you a better idea if that would help you.